# what does method mean/do in gtag event?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm reading the google analytics documentation and I'm slightly confused about what method means. In their documentation they have

`gtag('event', 'login', {'method': 'Google'});`
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data

When you go to the measure Analytics page, method isn't listed in. They list the following params for event

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

which doesn't list method. Does anyone know what this param does? And is it required to track events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `method` parameter is specific to the recommended `login` event. It tells you which method a user used to log in, for example `credentials` or `google-oauth`. Hence, it's not required (or applicable) to track GA4 events in general and it's not required (but recommended) for the `login` event.

| Name | Type | Required | Example value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| method | string | No | Google | The method used to login. |

(https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/events#login)

---

In GA-UA you could control the values for *Category*, *Action*, *Label* (the row data) (plus custom dimensions).

**Example:**

| Category | Action | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Interaction` | `Login` | `Google` |

In GA4, you can basically control the row data *and* the column names. (Gray fields can be set to any value).

**Example:**

| Event Name | `method` | `failed_attempts` | `...` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `login` | `Interaction` | `2` | `...` |

`method` is one of Google's recommended parameters, but you could also leave it out, give it a different name or add other parameters that you deem useful.